# creating facebook application

Tags: facebook, api, authentication

i have this problem..

I created account to develop facebook api for my apps..
I registered and created account and vertified with email and phone.
But when i try to create new app, i get this error:
You've been blocked from creating apps because we haven't been able to verify your account. You need to use your real name to maintain an account on Facebook

I dont get it, what do i have to do, to get my account vertified and working? I need this account only for development and i dont want to use account, cos other developers can see my password.

and when i try to ask this question anyware on facebook forums i get this message, so i dont know what to do:
This message contains blocked content that has previously been flagged as abusive or spammy

Btw, i added apps on my real facebook account, but i dont remember having any problems..

Answer (score 0):

If i not understand wrongly, did you mean that you are creating another facebook account for your development purpose? actually you can use your own account to create the facebook application. After that, you can grant access to others developer from the app. They can have the access to edit your application configuration too.

Regards,
Woolei - Facebook Consultant at www.woolei.com